# Mosca JS unable to publish message from server

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt, mosca

I am trying to add Mosca MQTT server to my existing Express application.
I want to to send just a welcome message to the just connected client, but it is not working.

```
const mqttServ = new mosca.Server({})
mqttServ.attachHttpServer(server)

var message = {
  topic: 'helloworld',
  payload: 'abcde', // or a Buffer
  qos: 0, // 0, 1, or 2
  retain: false // or true
}

mqttServ.on('clientConnected', (client) => {
  mqttServ.publish(message, client, () => {
    console.log('message sent')
  })
})
```

On the web page I have suscribed the client to the '/hello/world' topic, but I am not getting anything.

```
var client = mqtt.connect()

client.subscribe('helloworld')

client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
  console.log([topic, payload].join(": "))
  client.end()
})
```

-- update --
If I remove the client in the publish invocation, the message reaches the web page, but it is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your topics don't match in the code you have posted and MQTT topics should not start with a /

Comment: I have changed the topic into "helloworld" in both codes. But still is not working

Answer (score 0):

Publishing the message after the subscribe event did the trick

```
mqttServ.on('subscribed', (topic, client) => {
  mqttServ.publish(message, client)
})
```